# Using a pipe inside a for loop. How do I preserve the value of the variable inside the for loop

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I've been stuck for quite some time with the following code. It works but the variable loses the value that was set during the iterations.

I have the following code

```
  mistakes=0
  entered_chars=()


 word_length=0
 answer=""
 answer_guess=""


checkIfLetterInsideWord(){

exists=0
letter=$2

    word_array=`echo $1 | grep -o . `;

for (( i=1; i <= $word_length; i++))
    do
       if [[ "${1:$i-1:1}" = ${letter} ]]; then

          exists=1

          answer_guess=$(echo $answer_guess | sed "s/-/${letter}/{i}" )

       fi

 done

 echo $exists

}

askUserInput(){

    answer=$answer
    echo $answer
    echo "Please type a letter"
    read user_input


    if [ ! -z $user_input ]; then

    user_input=$(echo $user_input | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')

     if [ $(checkIfAlreadyEntered "$user_input") -eq 0 ]; then

        if [ $(checkIfLetterInsideWord $answer $user_input) -eq 0 ]; then 
        mistakes=$((mistakes + 1)); fi

        echo "Current mistake count; $mistakes "

        entered_chars+=($user_input)

    else
        echo "Char has already been entered"
    fi
else
    echo "You haven't entered any input!"
fi

}


guessTheWord() {

answer=$OPTARG
word_length=$(printf $answer | wc -m)

temp=$(echo $answer | sed 's/\(.\)/\1 /g')
array=($temp)


echo "The chosen word is $word_length long" 

gameOngoing=true


      for(( i=1; i<=$word_length; i++)) do
            answer_guess="$answer_guess-"
     done



while $gameOngoing
 do

echo $answer_guess

askUserInput $answer    



done




 }
```

I want to preserve the value of the variable answer_guess. I understand that it loses the value because of the usage of a pipeline inside the loop but I don't know to approach this problem.

Comment: Nothing in that code snippet will cause the value of `answer_guess` to be discarded. Please provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem you wish to solve.

Comment: `answer_guess` is not given a value except from the `sed`.  If it is empty on the first iteration then t will be empty for all the others.  Your `sed` line is suspicious, You have a close `}` when it should be a `)`, and why do you have `{i}`?  That's invalid on my version of `sed`, and you don't need a case insensitive substitution anyhow because of the character you are replacing.

Comment: Sorry that was a type over mistake with the ) 

I use the {i} for index, answer_guess is a variable that's filled. What I'm creating is a hangman game and initial, the answer_guess contains the value '-----'

What I'm doing is replacing the - with the right guessed letter

Comment: And I suppose that `"$1:$i-1:1}"` also contains a typo?  Maybe you meant `"${1:$i-1:1}"`?  And what about that `{i}` in the `sed` expression?  I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that.

Comment: You don't even need a loop here. `checkIfLetterInsideWord () { [[ $1 = *$letter* ]]; }`.

Comment: What you're trying to do looks like an attempt to implement a C / Java / whatever approach in `bash`, and though you could probably make it work, it seems rather non-idiomatic.  I, for one, have trouble imagining circumstances in which I would scan a shell variable's value character-by-character.

Comment: I added the full code, managed to copy it over from virtual os.

Comment: No one asked for full code, though it's good that you copied and pasted (or an equivalent) instead of retyping and thereby introducing errors.  The "Complete" in "[mcve]" refers to sufficiency to demonstrate the problem.  Follow the link if you are uncertain.

Comment: I'll try to recreate the issue in a minimalistic version :)

Comment: OK, got your complete code, and nothing happens!! This is because you don't call a function to start anything.  I suspect that the final trailing `}` is in the wrong place.  Also, `askUserInput()` has a `fi` missing, so that won't compile.  If you used consistent indentation it would be much easier to spot these sort of errors.

Comment: My mistake, there isn't a `fi` missing, however `checkIfAlreadyEntered` function is not there, so I can't test it.

Comment: Hi cdarke, it seemed it didn't copy over fully when I went over it. My issue has been resolved however and it's fully working now :) Despite everything, thank you!

Comment: A general comment:  all the variables in your script are globals.  You appear to be getting away with that in this case, but if you write functions for reuse between several scripts (one of their strengths) then they should be encapsulated.  Using globals is generally to be avoided, you should pass parameters instead.

Comment: I understand, it appears I need to re-evaluate the code and refactor where needed in order to meet the expected requirements. It's my first script so I appreciate all the tips and help that can make me improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
answer_guess=$(echo $answer_guess | sed "s/-/${letter}/{i}" )
```

replace the - with .

so your code becomes

```
answer_guess=$(echo $answer_guess | sed "s/./${letter}/{i}" )
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem has nothing do to with the pipe. Rather, it is that you call `checkIfLetterInsideWord` inside a command-substitution (`$(...)`). Command substitution executes in a subshell so environment changes in the function will not persist.

It would be better to rewrite `checkIfLetterInsideWord` so that it *returns* an exit status. Something like:

```
if [[ $exists ]]; then
  return 0 # Success
else
  return 1 # Failure
end
```

Then you could simply call it without worrying about a subshell:

```
if checkIfLetterInsideWord "$answer" "$user_input"; then
  # letter is in word
else
  # letter is not in word
fi
```

---

There are other issues with the code. I've limited this answer to the question about preserving the value of variables.

Comment: Your approach is logical and makes sense. I'm sorry for my late response but I will take your explanation with me as a helpful lesson. Thank you once again.